# Optional lookahead in regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this:

```
REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:%[VER#,SAH#]%,%SAH#%,F2:%KMSTAND%)
```

And I am trying to use the following regular expression to get all the characters after "F1:" until "F2":

```
(F1|F2):(.*?)(?:(?=,F))
```

It matches the first portion but it should also get the second. So that the lookahead function works only optional. What's wrong?

**Edit:**
My code:

```
Matcher fields = Pattern.compile("(F1|F2):(.*?)(?:(?=,F))").matcher(line);
while (fields.find()) {
    //do something with fields.group(2)
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: @mohit6up: Your regex doesn't give me the part after F2

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Deleting... The answer below looks just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So that the lookahead function works only optional. What's wrong?

An optional lookahead would be quite useless. And in your case, you *want* to lookahead after matching F2 - only you won't look out for `,F`, but for the string end.

Change your pattern to

```
(F1|F2):(.*?)(?=,F|\)) // "(F1|F2):(.*?)(?=,F|\\))" with double-escaped brace
// maybe:
(F\d):(.*?)(?=,F\d|\))
```

or

```
(F1|F2):(.*?)(?:$|(?=,F))
```

if you want to include the closing parenthesis

Comment: The regex `(F1|F2):(.*?)(?:$|(?=,F))` was very helpful. Thank you!